# maximum memory usage per Pod is reached but it is still within the limit

Tags: openshift

I got this confusing error from OpenShift during deployment

[image]

```
 Error creating: pods "jira-76-8fpnp" is forbidden: maximum memory usage per Pod is 8Gi, but limit is 8858370048.
```

At first I thought that is some conversion problem between gibibytes and gigabytes, but then I calculated online and it looks like the value of 8858370048 bytes is well over 8GB or 8Gi, but why this error occurs?

Comment: Do you have more than one container in the pod? The message suggests you might have a 8Gi and 256Mi container in same pod (or some other combination). They add up to 8858370048 bytes, which is greater than the quota of 8Gi.

Comment: You are totally right, the setup is two init containers with 256MB and two containers, one with 8Gi (Gibibytes - not Gigabytes) and one additional container limited to 256MiB.
It's just that this message is bit confused, this part in particular: `but limit is 8858370048.` ,

Answer (score 1):

I also recently got the same error template in my EKS deployment. I am not sure what the value at the end of the error refers to, however to resolve this error, we need to find out the `LimitRange` of the EKS Kubernetes deployment.

`kubectl describe limitrange -n <namespace> --kubeconfig=<location of your config file>`

```
Type        Resource  Min   Max  Default Request  Default Limit  Max Limit/Request Ratio
----        --------  ---   ---  ---------------  -------------  -----------------------
Pod         cpu       
Pod         memory    
Container   memory    
Container   cpu
```

We have to make sure that the resource.limits.cpu and resource.requests.memory value we provide for the containers are within the `Max` value above.

Also, if there are more than 1 container in the pod, have to ensure the aggregate of the resource.limits.cpu and resource.requests.memory values provided for each container in the deployment is less than `Max` for the pod.

This post here helped me get better understanding and to the solution: [Unable to set LimitRange: Creating Pods is forbidden[ maximum cpu usage is x but limit is y...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525499/unable-to-set-limitrange-creating-pods-is-forbidden-maximum-cpu-usage-is-x-but)

This is old question, but sharing just in case someone else also lands here when googling for this error msg.