# Unable to set LimitRange: Creating Pods is forbidden[ maximum cpu usage is x but limit is y...]

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 delpoyments in my namespace. None of the deployments specify any resource limits for either CPU or memory. I am trying to set the default min and max using LimitRange for all pods and their containers(existing and future) in this namespace. I've deployed a LimitRange resource to the namespace as defined below. However, when I redeploy, the deployments fail with errors (as listed below)

LimitRange:

```html
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "LimitRange"
metadata:
  name: "core-resource-limits"
  namespace: x
spec:
  limits:
    - type: "Pod"
      max:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 1Gi
      min:
        cpu: 2m
        memory: 50Mi
    - type: "Container"
      max:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 800Mi
      min:
        cpu: 1m
        memory: 50Mi
      default:
        cpu: 20m
        memory: 500Mi
      defaultRequest:
        cpu: 10m
        memory: 400Mi
      maxLimitRequestRatio:
        cpu: 4
```

[image: Error]
This is the error that I see

I don't understand where is 2040m coming from as its not defined in the LimitRange and its not defined in any of the deployments. Similarly all the other limit values. I have tried changing all these values to a bit higher/lower but I can't figure it out. Can someone explain what is wrong with this set of values?

Thanks

Edit:
All the pods are on the same node. The node limit are as follows:

1. CPU requests: 2.86
2. CPU limits: 48.55
3. Memory requests: 7.459
4. Memory limits: 28.342

Comment: What is the total limits of CPU and memory for that namespace? How many replicas you try to run?

Comment: I have just 1 replica. What do you mean by total memory limits for namespace? These are namespace wide and these are the only limits i've set in the namespace. Do you mean total limits for the node?

Comment: Is there any chance that you got ResourceQuota enabled for that namespace? `kubectl get quota` and `kubectl describe quota`

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand and explain in more detail what might be wrong here. Let's take a closer look at the overview of [Limit Range](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/):

- The administrator creates one `LimitRange` in one namespace.
- Users create resources like `Pods`, `Containers`, and `PersistentVolumeClaims` in the namespace.
- The `LimitRanger` admission controller enforces defaults and limits for all `Pods` and `Containers` that do not set compute resource requirements and tracks usage to ensure it does not exceed resource minimum, maximum and ratio defined in any `LimitRange` present in the namespace.
- If creating or updating a resource (`Pod`, `Container`, `PersistentVolumeClaim`) that violates a `LimitRange` constraint, the request to the API server will fail with an HTTP status code 403 FORBIDDEN and a message explaining the constraint that have been violated.
- If a `LimitRange` is activated in a namespace for compute resources like cpu and memory, users must specify requests or limits for those values. Otherwise, the system may reject Pod creation.
- `LimitRange` validations occurs only at Pod Admission stage, not on Running `Pods`.

As already mentioned by @FritzDuchardt the error message clearly states that the limits are misconfigured or wrongly enforced. This leads us to two ways:

- Check if there are any other limits set at the `Pod` level (`kubectl edit pod <pod_name>`).
- Within a namespace, a `Pod` or `Container` can consume as much CPU and memory as defined by the namespace's [resource quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/). Check if resource quotas are set with `kubectl describe quota`. In the case where the total limits of the namespace is less than the sum of the limits of the Pods/Containers, there may be contention for resources. In this case, the Containers or Pods will not be created.

Here is an example of [attempting to create a Pod that exceeds the maximum memory constraint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-constraint-namespace/#attempt-to-create-a-pod-that-exceeds-the-maximum-memory-constraint) which represents the same result as you are experiencing.

I hope this explains the topic and potential issues in more detail.
Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: TLDR, try `kubectl get limitrange` and try to describe it. You should have the limits set there

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, I would say your Pod resources limits are set higher than permitted by the LimitRange. Do a "kubectl edit" on the exact Pod in question to ensure there are not limits set.